# After changing jpa entity at runtime,select gives wrong result

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am doing some crud operations on db, And there is a situation that i cant understand how it works.
Im selecting records by a repository which extends `JpaRepository` Sample code is below.

```java
DBEntity currentrecord = entityrepository.findById("2");
currentrecord.setName("DEMO");
DBEntity test=entityrepository.findById("2");
```

Test object 'name' has been changed as DEMO without flushing previous changes,Why second `findById` query is not taking values from database?

My entity class and repository interface are below

```
@Entity
public class DBEntity implements Serializable {
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = " name is mandatory")
    @Size(max = 50, message = " name the max value should be 50")
    private String name;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends JpaRepository<DBEntity, String> {    
    @Query(value="SELECT t FROM DBEntity t where and t.id = ? and t.value = 1")
    Optional<DBEntity> findById(String id);     
}
```

Comment: can you please post your entityrepository and your Entity class?

Comment: what does the second `findById(2)` return? It should be returning the original value. After setting the `name` to DEMO, you haven't used an update query to reflect the name change in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your entity `DBEntity` will be a "managed entity" after the first `entityrepository.findById("2")` call. When you call `entityrepository.findById("2")` the second time there is no need to retrieve the entity from the database. The managed entity will be used.

Note, there is no need to define your own `findById` method, since you use `JpaRepository`. This method will be provided by `CrudRepository` in `JpaRepository`.

The annotation @Repository is also superfluous here.